# Unable to retrieve values from property files in Maven

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3, pom.xml

Iam using maven pom.xml ( just started learning )

I had some .properties files (for eg: log4j.properties), I should be able to retrieve values from them either in pom.xml or in web.xml file , I mean if I use something like ${somename.version} in pom.xml or web.xml, this value should be retrieved from .properties files.

My properties files are under as below:

```
src/main/resources/log4j.properties
src/main/env/dev/config.properties
```

iam trying as below, BUT unable to retrieve values from properties files.. iam doing something wrong.

```
<resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/env/dev</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
```

please suggest me.

Comment: Maybe you need the properties plugin? :)

Comment: which properties plugin I need to use? and Is that mandatory to use?

Comment: Try this: http://mojo.codehaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your configuration is wrong, for reading properties from file use:

```
<filters>
    <filter>src/main/resources/log4j.properties</filter>
</filters>
```

Your actual configuration is about what files should be filtered.

For more information and example go to: [Maven Resource Plugin - Filtering](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html)

---

You can also use [Properties Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/)

Comment: Could you please look into this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21018252/not-getting-values-from-properties-files-in-context-xml-file

Comment: Yes, I can, but can you upvote if this help you or inspire you? :)

Comment: I did, could u please answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21037291/difference-between-keeping-a-plugin-inside-a-project-and-inside-a-profile

Comment: You accept, upvoting is other thing :) I can look into it after work.

Answer (score 0):

Resource filtering is meant to set a property in pom.xml and then use it in a property file.

with ${somename.version} in log4j.properties and the appropriate code in pom.xml your ${somename.version} is replaced with what you typed in pom.xml

for example inside pom.xml

`<property>
<name>somename.version</name>
<value>123</value>
</property>`

in your log4j.property
${somename.version} will be replaced by 123

you will find your file with the replaced value inside the target directory after you launch a mvn package

resources filtering is used when you package with profiles. each profile can change the properties in pom.xml

your properties can hold values that change with environnement like configuration for windows or configuration for linux

Comment: could you please look into this, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21018252/not-getting-values-from-properties-files-in-context-xml-file