# Not getting values from properties files in context.xml file

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3, maven-plugin, pom.xml

I am unable to retrieve value from `.properties` file into my `context.xml`

**pom.xml** ( didn't mention dependencies )

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>


    <groupId>com</groupId>
    <artifactId>myproj</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.1</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>myproj</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <env>dev</env>
                <build.number>0</build.number>
                <svn.revision.number>0</svn.revision.number>
            </properties>
        </profile>

    </profiles>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>false</filtering>

            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/environment</directory>
                <filtering>false</filtering>

            </resource>
        </resources>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8</version>
                <configuration>
                    <printSummary>false</printSummary>
                    <redirectTestOutputToFile>true</redirectTestOutputToFile>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/*_Roo_*</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <configuration>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>false</downloadJavadocs>
                    <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildCommand>
                            <name>org.eclipse.ajdt.core.ajbuilder</name>
                            <arguments>
                                <aspectPath>org.springframework.aspects</aspectPath>
                            </arguments>
                        </buildCommand>
                        <buildCommand>
                            <name>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</name>
                        </buildCommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.eclipse.ajdt.ui.ajnature</projectnature>
                        <projectnature>com.springsource.sts.roo.core.nature</projectnature>
                        <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warName>myproj</warName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>



</project>
```

**context.xml** (inside src/main/webapp/META-INF)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Context>
 <!-- Specify a JDBC datasource -->
<Resource name="jdbc/mydb" auth="Container"
  type="javax.sql.DataSource" username="${database.usernameee}" password="${database.password}"
  driverClassName="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"
  url="jdbc:jtds:sybase://localhost:9000/common_db"
 maxActive="10" maxIdle="4" />
</Context>
```

**I have some `.properties` files inside under:**

```
src/main/resources
src/main/environment/dev
```

I am unable to get values inside my context.xml of **${database.usernameee}**  and **${database.password}**

**please suggest what went wrong?**

Comment: can anyone tell me what went wrong pls?

Comment: You want to substitute the `database.username` and `database.password` properties from the relevant *.properties into the `context.xml`?

Comment: @WillKeeling  YEP! and i updated my code bit above, made <filtering>false and removed <includes> tag, even then iam still not getting value in context.xml from a property file..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do the following:

1) Remove the `<resources>` section. It's not needed for the filtering you want to do and `src/main/resources` is the default - it doesn't need to specified separately.

```
<build>
    <!-- Delete the <resources> section -->
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>false</filtering>

        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/environment</directory>
            <filtering>false</filtering>

        </resource>
    </resources>
```

2) Add a `<filters>` element under `<build>` specifying the environment specific properties file

```
<build>
    <filters>
        <filter>src/main/environment/${env}/some.properties</filter>
    </filters>
    ...
```

The above assumes your properties files are called `some.properties` - so change this to the real name of your file.

3) Modify the configuration of the `maven-war-plugin`

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <webResources>
            <resource>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/META-INF/context.xml</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </webResources>
        <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
        <webXml>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
        <warName>myproj</warName>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

That will now filter the `context.xml` using the environment specific properties - depending upon what profile you used.

(note that you may have a typo in 'database.usernameee' - as it has extra **ee** at the end)

Comment: wow, thanks a lot! BUT I had one doubt:  what does below tags do?

 <webResources>
            <resource>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/META-INF/context.xml</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </webResources>

Comment: I didnt understood how below tags are useful for me:

<warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
                    <webXml>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>

Comment: The `<resource>` tag inside `<webResources>` tells the maven war plugin to filter the `src/main/webapp` folder but only include the `context.xml` when doing the filtering. Yes you can probably safely remove `<webXml>` and `<warSourceDirectory>` as these just restate the defaults.

Comment: ok thnq! :) Could you please answer for my query B), here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21037291/difference-between-keeping-a-plugin-inside-a-project-and-inside-a-profile

Comment: Consider upvoting your answers too, to upvote click on arrow :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get your Maven properties from external files (not from properties inside POM's), you should use Maven Filters: [see here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/resources-mojo.html#filters) and [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html).

Comment: Thanq! :) , could u please answer for my query B), here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21037291/difference-between-keeping-a-plugin-inside-a-project-and-inside-a-profile