# difference between keeping a plugin inside a project and inside a profile

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3, maven-plugin, pom.xml

Can anyone please explain the functionality for below?

**A)** Actually below code is working for me, BUT I didnt understood why we need to use  below for **maven-war-plugin**

```
<warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
                    <webXml>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
```

B) whats the difference between keeping a plugin inside a project and inside a profile? ( say **maven-surefire-plugin** ) which way is better (assume I MUST use `<profile>` tag in my pom.xml)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Part A

`warSourceDirectory` is directory for static web files, jsp, images, WEB-INF etc. The default value is good, so you dont need to change this parameter.

`webXml` - is location of [web.xml](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web.xml) file, deployment description. With spring boot you dont need web.xml at all. Set parameter [failOnMissingWebXml](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html#failOnMissingWebXml) to `false`.

### Part B

Plugin defined inside a project are used by this project always. Plugin defined in profile are used only when you enable profile - so this plugin is not default.

Comment: So, if I use profiles, whatever the plugins I use MUST be inside profile only? actually iam not sure which plugin should be used inside profile and which should be inside project... So, please suggest me...

Comment: Plugin defined in profile can override plugin from project. It is not a must, if you use profile, then still plugin form project are used.